# While Initializing An Object Array what are the defaults values

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

I have this array `Cards[] temp = new Cards[13];`  where Cards is a class having 52 object. as per my knowledge this statement will create an array which hold 13 objects of Cards data type. i just want to know before putting the value what values are in this array a garbage of NULL ?
i mean after writing

```
Cards[] temp = new Cards[13];
```

and before putting real values what are the elements exist after this statement. Either Null or some garbage. more explanation is at compile time the memory of 13 object will dynamically allocate to the array or Cards I want to know what are the values in that memory at compile time. Wither NULL or some garbage ?

Comment: You could have easily checked it by printing the array elements.

Comment: initialized to NULL and no garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java all object references are `initialized as null` if no values provided.

```
Cards[] temp = new Cards[13];
```

After this line `temp[0],temp [1] ....temp[12]` values are assigned to null.

You need  to create object like below.

```
for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
      temp = new Cards();
}
```

Comment: Object *references* are initialized as null.

Answer (score 5):

They're initialized to null. They can't be garbage.

Also the array holds 13 references, not 13 objects. The last part of your question I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you said

`Cards[] temp = new Cards[13];`

it means that you have created and array named temp which contain 13 references. These references can point to 13 Cards object. Also if you have 52 instance variables for the individual cards it will all set to null as they are instance variables. I hope I understood your question well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Section 'Default Values':

```
byte    0

short   0

int     0

long    0L

float   0.0f

double  0.0d

char    '\u0000'

String (or any object)      null

boolean     false
```

That means that each object in your array will have a default value of `null`. No garbage values like other languages, just `null`.

You can try it for yourself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(temp[i]);
}
```